# Stripe error the customer has not entered their payment method on wix website

Tags: stripe-payments, velo

I am integrating stripe payment gateway on wix website. Below are the steps i followed to integrate the payment.

1. Login to wix website dashboard.
2. From left sidebar -> payment methods
3. From payments screen, i added stripe.

On checkout page it is showing perfect. Issue that when user submit credit card details, it says technical error.

Inside stripe account in all payments it is showing that transaction incomplete: ** the customer has not entered their payment method **

[image]

One thing here is worthy to mention that, stripe account currency is in Indian Rupee, and on website user is paying in USD. Is this creating any issue? i think stripe automatically converts the currencies.

Please let me know your answers, opinions and suggestions. Thank you

Comment: The payment intent is in Incomplete status. You could click the payment and go to the detail page and see why. 
In india, your customer will receive an OTP when trying to complete the payment, some of the payment failed might due to that they did not complete that properly.

Comment: @wsw as per customer statement, he is able to use his that card anywhere online. He doesn't face any kind of difficulty to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the currency resolved the issue.

Comment: I am facing same the problem. Customer currency is USD, and stripe accnt currency is INR. Where did you change the currency?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkGbl.png)    *const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
amount: total,
currency: "usd",
});*

**In your code change currency to your default currency that is showing on [stripes](https://dashboard.stripe.com/), For Example, if your default currency on stripes is in INR(Indian Rupees), then change your code to:-**

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: "inr",
  });
```